# Disable a gvim plugin from with in gvim using a shortcut

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm using a gvim plugin called AutoCompIPop which allows auto completion using a pop-up menu. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879

However, I have certain files that a huge and have a number of variables. Because of this, the pop-menu slows the editor to a halt.

Is there a way for me to disable that particular plugin when I'm in the said huge file but not everywhere else?

Can a plugin be unloaded/disabled once it is loaded at start-up using a key? This would allow me to disable this plugin only in certain files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular plugin has a command to disable it (not the case with all plugins). To disable it type

```
:AcpDisable<Enter>
```

If there's a certain filetype you know will always be huge you can use an autocommand in your `~/.vimrc` to persistently disable it. It's wise to also disable syntax highlighting on very large files as it can slow vim down significantly.

```
au BufRead,BufEnter *.dat syn off | AcpDisable
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Now, to tack on to this, I was thinking of having a shortcut for :AcpDisable. I tried :AcpEnable and that enables the plugin as expected. Is there a way to have same shortcut that will toggle between the two? (I have many shortcuts and am running out of keys!)

Comment: Look for a variable you can check to see if its enabled or not then use an if statement to either enable or disable it in the mapping. Create a function for more convenient organization.